I ran into permission issue when building Milvus from source on remote cluster (linux)
I would like to create a milvus server on a remote cluster. Since I prefer not to use docker there, I tried to build from source:
# Clone github repository.
$ git clone https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus.git

# Install third-party dependencies.
$ cd milvus/
$ ./scripts/install_deps.sh

# Compile Milvus.
$ make

and then set the path sudo ldconfig /opt/milvus/internal/core/output/lib/
but when i try to run the start_cluster.sh (https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus/blob/master/scripts/start_cluster.sh) file I get permission issues:
Starting rootcoord...
Starting datacoord...
Starting datanode...
./scripts/start_cluster.sh: line 31: /tmp/rootcoord.log: Permission denied
Starting proxy...
./scripts/start_cluster.sh: line 34: /tmp/datacoord.log: Permission denied
Starting querycoord...
Starting querynode...
Starting indexcoord...
./scripts/start_cluster.sh: line 40: /tmp/proxy.log: Permission denied
Starting indexnode...
./scripts/start_cluster.sh: line 43: /tmp/querycoord.log: Permission denied
./scripts/start_cluster.sh: line 46: /tmp/querynode.log: Permission denied

I also tried to create a milvus database using the milvus-cli(https://github.com/zilliztech/milvus_cli), but I have an issue to connect:
milvus_cli > connect -uri http://127.0.0.1:19530
Connect to Milvus error!<MilvusException: (code=2, message=Fail connecting to server on 127.0.0.1:19530, illegal connection params or server unavailable)>

I saw this issue: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/runtime-error-milvusexception-code-2-message-fail-connecting-to-server-on-127-0-0-1-19530-timeout/45338 but (I think) it does not provide a solution for me.
Important to note that I have sudo rights on that cluster so should not be a permission error to connect to the server.
Please feel free to ask for clarifications, probably there is some imporant information I didn't share here?
Many thanks for any help from a new Milvus user!

Having sudo permissions for your Linux users is not sufficient. If you want to run the start_cluster.sh script as root, you must run it as sudo start_cluster.sh, meaning that you are not supposed to have Milvus run as root in that case.
Although it is quite weird how your user does not have access to files in the /tmp directory. Can you double check that you did not accidentally change the access permissions on the /tmp folder?
Also check if the files /tmp/rootcoord.log etc exist, and if they do exist, delete them.
This post may help with your issue too: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71625
